# Django Across All Apps

Tags: python, django

I am creating a rather large django project which will require two things.  1) I need a few template files to be accessible across all apps.  2) I need a model to be accessible across all apps.  How do I go about doing that?

As far as the templates are concerned, it seems adding it to the TEMPLATES directive doesn't work.

As far as the models are concerned, can I have a models.py in the project/project folder or something like that to be accessible by all apps?

Django 1.10 and Python 3.5

```
TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': ['templates'],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
[...]
```

Comment: for the models you just have to import them in your app `from  otherapp.models import A, B`

Comment: Nice, I didn't realize.  THanks.

Comment: Templates aren't in any way constrained to apps, so I'm not sure what you're asking here.

Comment: if I execute `return render(request,"template.html")` from within an app, it's looking for a templates folder inside of that app.  I want to have template.html in the `project/project/templates` folder, not the `project/app/templates` folder.

Comment: According to the djengo documentation, by adding a path to the `DIRS: []` directive in my settings.py it should add it to the list of search paths for templates.  https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/settings/#std:setting-TEMPLATES-DIRS

Comment: for the `project/project` to be used you'd need to add `DIRS: ['project']`. With your code you can use templates inside `project/templates` and inside every `app/templates`

Comment: I've done that as you can see above.  It seems regardless of what I put in here I consistently get **Exception Type: TemplateDoesNotExist**

Comment: Is there a way to provoke debug mode to show all the paths it's looking for templates?  I made an error above also.  I didn't mean `project/project/templates` , I just mean't `project/templates` .

Answer (score 0):

Was able to work it out with this work around.

```
BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))

TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [BASE_DIR + '/templates'],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
[...]
```